# winspool.drv SetDefaultPrinter returns false

Tags: c#, windows, printing, driver, printers

In one of our application we are using winspool.drv SetDefaultPrinter(abc) method. On some machines it works fine, but on other it doesn't work (call to SetDefaultPrinter() method returns false).

My earlier guess was may be winspool.drv is missing from the machine where it doesn't work. However, winspool.drv exists on all the machines.

Could anyone please explain under what circumstances does SetDefaultPrinter(..) return false (0) and what could I do to make the call successful?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the printername is available on the workstation?

```
foreach (string sAvailable in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    XML.log("Available printer " + sAvailable, Constants.logDebug);
    if (sPrinter == sAvailable)
    {
       break;
    }
}
```